# Как проверить работоспособность Geoip

Tags: php, proxy, geoip, location

Может есть какие-то сервисы которые помогут зайти на сайт под разными ip? необходимо проверить правильно ли определяется страна 
[Сам сайт где определяю откуда зашел пользователь](http://www.cr35020.tmweb.ru/geo.php)

Comment: через прокси зайди и проверь, есть списки прокси по странам.

Answer (score 0):

скачать оперу включть впн...
скачать тор...
поставить в хром фригейт...